# VSCode - source.organizeImports is not working in .vue files

Tags: vuejs2, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get my editor to remove unused imports

```
"editor.formatOnPaste": false,
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.organizeImports": true,
    "source.fixAll": true
  },
```

This works fine on my main entry point(.js file), but not on anything with a .vue extension does not work.

Has anyone got this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Organize imports is currently not supported by the Vue extension Vetur ([tracked here](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur/issues/843))

The organize imports feature has to be implemented per-language by an extension. Please consider helping out Vetur with a PR if you are interested in getting it supported for Vue

Comment: It is supported now.